# XAMPP Mysql 2002 error

Tags: mysql, xampp

So I have been trying to get XAMPP up and running for awhile now. I see there is plenty of documentation on this problem but most of them don't seem to be helping my situation so I would really appreciate someones help walking me through this.
Ok when I started apache wouldn't start but when I changed it so that it would be using port 85 that at least started. My next problem has been with MySql. It is currently running on port 3306 (I had something else that was using that port but I deleted it) when I click to start MySql it just says it is attempting to start but doesn't do anything. When I go to phpMyAdmin I get this error message

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
Are there any procedures I can go though to get this thing up and running?!

Comment: Have you turned mysql on? There should be mysql_start.bat -file (and all other) in xampp directory

Comment: #GoodGodThankYou! I can now access phpMyAdmin. Oddly enough on the control panel it says nothing about mysql running (it isnt highlighted green and stating what port it is running on), In the message/error display a message does say that mysql is already running on port 3306 though.